# How to cut circle in the canvas element

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas

I want to cut transparent circle from canvas rectangle which have transparency set to `rgba(0,0,0,0.7)`. When I'm trying to cut the circle then figure path inside is grayed. Canvas is over the picture.
Expected behaviour attached.

Grayed circle figure:
[image: example]

Expected circle:
[image: expected result]

My JS code:

```js
context.save()  
context.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"
context.fillRect(0,0, 700, 100)
context.save()
context.globalCompositeOperation= "destination-out"
context.beginPath()
context.arc(400,100, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)
context.fill()
context.restore()
```

Comment: Also looking for the same thing.